# How to save tem file in my system with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, temporary-files

i try to add geometry layer to my gis app from shb layer
i use Django for doing that and for uploading file i use serializer FileField
now my main question is How can i save temporary file to my system in python
is there any way to do that?

if there is please help me about that

Comment: Hi Emad, take a look at the build in [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) library. I think this should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619600/how-to-generate-temporary-file-in-django-and-then-destroy) is a similar question that has already been answered.

TL/DR

```py
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False) as f:
    f.write("hello world")

path_to_tempfile = f.name
```